# How to add AdaptiveCard to QnA Bot in Python

Tags: python, azure, botframework, azure-cognitive-services, azure-qna-maker

I wish to use some AdaptiveCard with my QnA python bot.
I use sample code from botbuilder repo:

```
from botbuilder.ai.qna import QnAMaker, QnAMakerEndpoint
from botbuilder.core import ActivityHandler, MessageFactory, TurnContext
from botbuilder.schema import ChannelAccount

from config import DefaultConfig
    
class QnABot(ActivityHandler):
    def __init__(self, config: DefaultConfig):
        self.qna_maker = QnAMaker(
            QnAMakerEndpoint(
                knowledge_base_id=config.QNA_KNOWLEDGEBASE_ID,
                endpoint_key=config.QNA_ENDPOINT_KEY,
                host=config.QNA_ENDPOINT_HOST,
            )
        )

    async def on_members_added_activity(
        self, members_added: [ChannelAccount], turn_context: TurnContext
    ):
        for member in members_added:
            if member.id != turn_context.activity.recipient.id:
                await turn_context.send_activity(
                    "Hallo!"
                )

    async def on_message_activity(self, turn_context: TurnContext):
        # The actual call to the QnA Maker service.
        response = await self.qna_maker.get_answers(turn_context)
        if response and len(response) > 0:
            await turn_context.send_activity(MessageFactory.text(response[0].answer))
        else:
            await turn_context.send_activity("Ich kann nicht")
```

So how I have to configure qna_maker.get_answers() and rows in QnA Knowledge Base, for using AdaptiveCards like an answer for a question?

**UPD**

What I wish to return answer inside card:

```
card = HeroCard(
    title="Answer Title here",
    subtitle="short answer",
    buttons=[task_module_action], #task_module_action - button which have to show long variant of answer
)
```

Comment: Can you provide an example of an Adaptive Card you'd like to use as an answer?

Comment: @KyleDelaney Hi! I made update with Hero Card

Comment: Hero cards are different from Adaptive Cards. Do you want to send a hero card or an Adaptive Card? What channel are you using?

Comment: Are you still working on this?

Comment: @KyleDelaney Hi! Thanks for support! Now I use CardFactory.adaptive_card({//json card}) . I will do answer later . Thank you for support. If you can give some critic for my future answer, welc! Is good!